# Condition to trigger flow only once for each item created/modified

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a flow that does the following: When a item Sharepoint item is created or modified > add a row to a table > send an email

However, I want it to just do it the first time the item is created or modified, because now it’s just creating a new row for the same item every time I modify the item. If that item is modified again, I want it to do nothing.

Is it possible to add a condition that triggers the flow only the first time the item is created/modified? Or alternatively, for it to check if that item’s info already exists in the spreadsheet, and if it does then it will not create a row or send an email?

Simply changing to 'When an item is created' is not an option as my flow has a specific trigger condition (triggered when a specific column is changed).

[image: EDIT: image]

Comment: Of course! Every item has an ID, make sure you store the ID in your Excel table and then check for its existence prior to adding it.

Comment: Thanks but how do I check for its ID?

Comment: Show your flow and maybe I can take it to the next step.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question about logic.  The best way to achieve what you're wanting is to first determine if the row exists.  To do that, use the `Get a row` operation from the Excel Online connector.

[image: Get a row]

If the row doesn't exist, it will tell you.

[image: Row doesn't exist]

From there, you need to configure the run after settings to make sure it will continue if the operation errors.

[image: Run After 1]

[image: Run After 2]

So the end result is ...

1. If the row **IS** found, the flow will simply stop and not continue on.
2. If the row **IS NOT** found, it will keep going and then execute your operation to add the row.

[image: Result]